# Проверка checkbox на checked внутри редиректа js

Tags: javascript, php, html

Вот код, в котором идет передача значения для переменной, которая используется в php файле на другом сайте

```
$(function(){
    $('.booking').on(_clickEvent, function(e){
        addToCart(this.id, true);
    });

    $('.custom-control-input').change(function(){
        addToCart(this.id);
    });

    $('#BookingSubmit').on(_clickEvent, function(){
        var isValid = true;
        $('div.window').find('.form-control').each(function(){
            if ( $(this).prop('required') &&  $(this).val().length < $(this).attr('minlength') ) {
                $(this).addClass('is-invalid');
                new Noty({type: 'error', text: 'Заполните обязательные поля!'}).show();
                isValid = false;
                return false;
            }
        });
        if ( isValid ) {
            var data = JSON.stringify({
                'time': $('#purchaserTime').val(),
                'date': $('#purchaserDate').val(),
                'product': $('#BookingOrder').text() + ' - ' + $('#purchaserHall').val(),
                'city': $('#purchaserCity').val(),
                'phone': $('#purchaserNumber').val()
            });
            $.redirect('https://'+pd+'pay/', {
                'amount': totalPrice,
                'description': 'Город - ' + $('#purchaserCity').val(),
                'merchant_name': $('#BookingOrder').text(),
                'name_buyer' : $('#purchaserName').val(),
                'phone_buyer': $('#purchaserNumber').val(),
                'dop_first' : $('#option1').val(),
                'dop_second' : $('#option2').val()                              
            });
        }
    });
```

Если dop_first и dop_second оставить в таком виде, то они в пхп код всегда будут передавать on, а мне нужна проверка на то, активирован ли чекбокс.
Пробовал вот такой код для двух чекбоксов:

```
$('#option1').on('click', function () {
    if ( $(this).prop('checked', true) ) {
        'dop_first' : $('#option1').vol()
    }
})
```

```
$('#option2').on('click', function () {
    if ( $(this).prop('checked', true) ) {
        'dop_first' : $('#option2').vol()
    }
})
```

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        $.redirect('https://'+pd+'pay/', {
            'amount': totalPrice,
            'description': 'Город - ' + $('#purchaserCity').val(),
            'merchant_name': $('#BookingOrder').text(),
            'name_buyer' : $('#purchaserName').val(),
            'phone_buyer': $('#purchaserNumber').val(),
            'dop_first' : $('#option1:checked').val(),
            'dop_second' : $('#option2:checked').val()
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй заюзать `.checked` вместо .val(), оно возвращает `true` если зачекано или `false` если нет